# Selecting distinct, separate polydata in VTK

Tags: python, c++, vtk, dicom, paraview

Using VTK I managed to slice a volume and get contours of three coronary blood vessels with vtkFeatureEdges.
[image: Contours of blood vessels]

Is there a VTK way of selecting one of these? What I'm after is a polyData with slice of one vessel only (somewhat similar to [scipy label](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html)). I could do this manually by recreating points connectivity from cells but maybe there is a ready-to-use filter that I don't know about?

I'm using Python bindings but I think C++ answer would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `Connectivity` filter to generate a RegionID array for each vessel
- Use Edit->FindData to create a selection based on the RegionID array
- use `Extract Selection` filter to extract it.

This is a ParaView answer as you tagged the question as ParaView. But all these filter and selection mechanism are available in VTK as well.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. I appreciate your answer very much!